# c# - HtmlAgilityPack How to scraping lazy loading webpage?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to force the load of lazyloading website? It's now takes 8 items but needs to be 40 or is there an other way to scrape the page?

Mycode:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(item.WebPage());

            Console.WriteLine(item.WebPage());
            Console.WriteLine(web.RequestDuration + "ms");
            var HeaderNames = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//div[@class='item-title']").ToList();
            var HeaderPrices = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//span[@class='price-format']").ToList();
```

Comment: What version of .net are you targeting? what is the type of your app?

Comment: atm i'm using a console application, just testing some things and i'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: if you are in Windows you could probably get a browser control, load the whole page, then feed that to HAP.

Comment: got problems with the regular webbrowser in the windows form application, some websites won't load.

Comment: Try CefSharp: http://cefsharp.github.io/

Comment: There is not a way to do this with HTMLAgilityPack? Because I Don't like the way how CefSharp is opperate.

Comment: AFAIC HAP uses something like `HttpClient` under the covers - that will download the HTML page (e.g. `index.html`) but won't download and apply referenced js or css files. So if you are targeting an SPA or a similar dynamic app, you need an actual browser to execute that for you so you can extract the data from processes HTML